# Creating unique non guessable base 36 id

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, unique, base36

For an application similar to URL shortener services, I want to create non guessable id's, which you're all familiar with I presume. Here's an example of such an id:

http://example.com/sd23t9

What is a good and efficient technique to generate these, with minimal (or no) risk of collision when inserting these as a primary key in a database table?

**EDIT:**
Piskvor makes an excellent point of course. I should have mentioned that I meant minimal collision risk before the 36^6 limit is met.

**EDIT 2**
Eh, scrap that, his point was illustrating much more than that of course. Hmmm. Pregenerating a table with id's then, perhaps (like I've read elsewhere already)? Would that be the most efficient technique when i'm bound to the 36^6 and none-consecutive constraints perhaps?

Comment: There's always a risk of collision: assuming from your example that you'd have `[a-z0-9]{6}` IDs, as soon as you have 2,176,782,336 IDs, a collision is 100% guaranteed (no more available keys). Due to birthday effect, you'll get collisions much, *much* sooner: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_effect#Cast_as_a_collision_problem . With such a small keyspace, there **isn't** a way to avoid collisions - you'll need to have some sort of collision *recovery* instead (e.g. generate an ID until it doesn't collide - this will get progressively slower as the keyspace is being filled).

Comment: There's always risk of collision, but you can just generate a new one if you get a constraint violation.

Comment: If you expect to generate a lot of IDs, you could start with less digits and increase the length gradually when you consistently get too many collisions. That way you start even shorter and it works even if you expect loads of IDs.

Comment: @Mrki: Great minds think alike :) It will still take progressively more time as shorter keyspaces fill up, but should terminate in a few iterations (although it could *very theoretically* generate long IDs).

Comment: @fireeyedboy: The method you use for generating the _random_ IDs doesn't matter - the probability of a collision comes from the *number* of IDs you already have. You could generate them sequentially, but that's 1) totaly non-random and therefore 2) totaly guessable, not to mention 3) useless as an URL shortener ("was it /aaaqaaa, or /aaaaqaa?")

Comment: @Piskvor: I'm not sure I follow your last reasoning. But with pregenerating I meant pregenerate all possible id's (36^6) and then shuffle the id's of course. Or am I being dense here? :P

Comment: @fireeyedboy: I'll post another answer with pre-generated IDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Set ID length. // e.g. 6
do {
  Generate a short random ID of the given length
  Collision?
   - No:
      DONE!
   - Yes:
      increase ID length
 } while true
```

For any finite ID length, there's always a risk of collision: assuming from your example that you'd have [a-z0-9]{6} IDs, as soon as you have 2,176,782,336 IDs, a collision is 100% guaranteed (no more available keys). Due to [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem), you'll get collisions much, much sooner. With such a small keyspace, there isn't a way to avoid collisions - you'll need to have some sort of collision recovery instead.

You could generate an ID until it doesn't collide - but this will get progressively slower as the keyspace is being filled: imagine a keyspace of [a-z], with [a-n] and [p-z] already taken - now every new random ID is more likely to collide than not; and when you completely fill the keyspace, the loop will not terminate at all.

The algorithm I propose is maybe overcautious in this regard: if it finds a collision, it will try progressively longer IDs (as it assumes "collision => not feasible to check the shorter keyspace"). Although it's not efficient, it's likely to find a non-colliding ID within a few iterations.

Comment: excellent points and answer. Would you think it more sensible to pregenerate a table with id's then perhaps (as was already suggested elsewhere on this site I think)?

Comment: Far too much data with far too little value. Just change his original metacode to increase length when you first get X consecutive collisions and/or a collision Y% of the time. (off the top of my head I'd go for X=3, Y=50%).

Comment: @fireeyedboy: Depending on the traffic you're hoping to see - but unless your site needs to assign hundreds of IDs per second, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @Mrki and @Piskvor: fair points too of course. @Piskvor: My goal is to keep it short as possible (max length 6, for use in services like Twitter et al.) so I'ld probably go for decreasing the length then (to avoid early guessability, not starting with short length). But very useful answer. Thank you.

Comment: Anyway, gotto run right now. I'll get back if need be. Thanks again so far.

Answer (score 4):

A bit of a weird idea. Why not to use permutations? 
e.g. 
you have a set of values [0-9a-z] 
when you generate first id. you take a first permutation in lexicographical order. then second and so on.
to make it appear less guessable you can change the rules of lexicographic order. say 'a' goes after 't' or something like that. you can use tuple instead of a full permutations as well.
This will ensure there is no collisions.

What this idea is actually about is making some sort of a two way hash function. basically if you are able to encode number "1" in some way to get something like "q8d3dw" and be able to decode "q8d3dw" back to "1" you can be certain that this function will give you unique strings for all the values from 1 to 36^6.

The problem is actually selecting this function.  The easy way would be to associate "1" to "000000", "2" to "000001", "12" to "00000b". Basically arrange all available strings in lexicographical order and select the string on a position which is equal to the id.  This however is really easy to guess. So what you could do is to artificially change rules of lexicographic order. Say instead of having a normal order(0,1,2,3...a,b,c...x,y,z) you could shuffle it a bit and get something like (a,5,t,3...). This will produce a bit more obfuscated results. However it will still be quite guessable because the first element would be "aaaaaa", second "aaaaa5", then "aaaaat". So you can change rules of lexicographic order even further, making them depended on the position of the character. Say order for the first char id (a,5,t,3...) for the second one (y,7,3,r...), etc.

Now, i will not post any pseudo code as it will be quite a long one. And I'm not advising you to go with that route unless you are interested in creating this sort of algorithms for fun :). However if you will go with this route it could be a very efficient way of generating this id's with no chance of collision. And I'll advise you to read volume 4 of "Art of computer programming" by Dr Donald Knuth.  There are lots of suggestions in implementation of such algorithms.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your answer. Although your answer sounds appealing, I have a hard time imagining what you have in mind exactly, as I'm not very well versed in these mathematical principles. If it's not too much trouble would you care to elaborate with a small example (maybe some pseudo code) of what you mean? I usually understand better by example than by mathematical theory (shouldn't have dropped maths so early in shool I guess :-/ ). Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean now. Yes this looks like a very reasonable approach. And I understand it enough now to transform it into a coded algorithm. Sounds like a fun little puzzle to solve. Thank you. Out of curiosity though: is the reason you don't particularly advise on using this, because of the 'security through obscurity' factor? For what it's worth; I haven't figured out how important security of this applications trait will be for me, yet, so I might very well end up using this, if security ends up not being *that* important for me. But I have to ponder on its implications a bit more.

Comment: The only reason not to use it, is the amount of time it will take to implement it. Apart from that this algorithm should be fast, reliable and actually quite secure(if orders for each char are random).

Answer (score 2):

@ivan: here is an implementation.

First you need the 6 strings, here's code to generate them:

```
$letters = range('a', 'z');
$numbers = range(0, 9);
$char_list = array_merge_recursive($letters, $numbers);
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    shuffle($char_list);
    echo '$mysterykey[' . $i . "] = '" . implode($char_list) . "';\n";
}
```

Then you can use the output from that in the function:

```
function int_to_x36($value) {
    $mysterykey[0] = 'awkbs81t3jyg20v4qhoxzcuenr65dfimlp97';
    $mysterykey[1] = 'ut17qclz96n3msky8jwp4r25gdvhxo0biaef';
    $mysterykey[2] = 'cewszx142nph05mi9ulafbdvy36o8gq7trjk';
    $mysterykey[3] = '37hp28wjdqe5vnlzxofrsybu4im90k16agtc';
    $mysterykey[4] = 'n9a3jksl5ct0eqfzo7pvgyd4m2hiu18xrb6w';
    $mysterykey[5] = 'mq0nbk3zs529gu4tecli8j176vardxoypfwh';

    $x36 = array();
    for ($i = 5; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $x36[$i] = 0;  
        $y = pow(36, $i);

        if ($value >= $y) {
            $z = floor($value/$y);
            $value = $value - ($z * $y);
            $x36[$i] = $z;
        }   
    }      

    $encoded = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $encoded .= $mysterykey[$i][$x36[$i]];
    }

    return $encoded;
}

function x36_to_int($value) {
    $mysterykey[0] = 'awkbs81t3jyg20v4qhoxzcuenr65dfimlp97';
    $mysterykey[1] = 'ut17qclz96n3msky8jwp4r25gdvhxo0biaef';
    $mysterykey[2] = 'cewszx142nph05mi9ulafbdvy36o8gq7trjk';
    $mysterykey[3] = '37hp28wjdqe5vnlzxofrsybu4im90k16agtc';
    $mysterykey[4] = 'n9a3jksl5ct0eqfzo7pvgyd4m2hiu18xrb6w';
    $mysterykey[5] = 'mq0nbk3zs529gu4tecli8j176vardxoypfwh';

    $value36 = str_split($value);

    $x36 = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $x36[$i] = strpos($mysterykey[$i], $value36[$i]);
    }

    $x = 0;
    for ($i = 5; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $x += $x36[$i] * pow(36, $i);
    }      

    return $x;
}
```

I'm sure I've overlooked something but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Big random number and SHA-256 Hash for example? You can shorten it later to fit your needs.

Comment: Why bother with the hash at all? Why not just generate a big random number and leave it at that? (After all, an SHA-256 hash is just a 256-bit number.)

Comment: because he wanted alphanum characters :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what LukeH meant was that you could just as well take the HEX representation of a random number.

Answer (score 1):

If the site is sufficiently large, and I mean **large** - as in "we need hundreds of new IDs assigned per second" (which will have other problems, e.g. exhaust the 36^6 keyspace under a year), you could pre-generate the keys and assign them.

The following is a pseudocode example - in such a large-traffic site, you'd probably need to optimize the algorithms used.

Pre-generating is trivial - just start at `000000` and go all the way to `zzzzzz`, insert each row into a table and mark them unused:

```
 ID     | used
==============
 000000   0   
 000001   0   
 ...
 zzzzzz   0
```

When you get a request for new ID, select a random one and mark it used (danger! concurrency issues!):

```
SELECT ID FROM ids WHERE RAND() LIMIT 1
UPDATE ids SET used = 1, url=what_you_want_shortened WHERE ID = whatever_you_got_from_previous_query
```

You'll run into efficiency issues (e.g. with `WHERE RAND()`, table locking, et al.), but it is doable.

Comment: Hi Piskvor, thanks for another useful answer. But I was actually thinking of a pre-shuffled table with incrementing primary key and than pop or unshift a record each time. I think that would deflect any concurrency issues as well, wouldn't it? (Or maybe I'm overlooking something vital here). I'm gonna run some test to see how I could efficiently pre-shuffle a huge array of data like that. I could imagine PHP will choke on it. But I'll have to try, to find out. :) Thanks again. If you feel like it, let me know what you think of my plan. Thanks again!

Comment: PS.: I have to say though, that your earlier answer is more appealing to me right now, because it allows for a larger number of id's (with decrementing lengths and all), because pregenerating a table from `0` to `zzzzzz` would be stretching it a bit too much I think.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: ah, that would work, somewhat. But yes, I'd say this way to do it seems needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not averse to bringing in a .NET dll, I've created a project to do exactly this. Source is [on GitHub here](https://github.com/piranout/Funcular.IdGenerators), and binaries are in the [IdGenerator NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Funcular.IdGenerators/).

It gives you ordered sequences and/or random values of user-specified length, all in base-36. Ids are universally unique, even with multiple id generator instances or in a distributed environment.

```
var generator = new Base36IdGenerator(
                numTimestampCharacters: 11, 
                numServerCharacters: 4, 
                numRandomCharacters: 5, 
                reservedValue: "", 
                delimiter: "-", 
                delimiterPositions: new[] {15, 10, 5});

// This instance would give you a 20-character Id, with an
// 11-character timestamp, 4-character servername hash, 
// and 5 character random sequence. This gives you 1.6 million
// hash combinations for the server component, and 60 million
// possible combinations for the random sequence. Timestamp is
// microseconds since epoch:
Console.WriteLine(generator.NewId());
// 040VZC6SL01003BZ00R2

// Argument name specified for readability only:
Console.WriteLine(generator.NewId(delimited: true));
// 040VZ-C6SL0-1003B-Z00R2
```

Of course if you're more interested in the string not being guessable than in having an ordered sequence, you could just use the GetRandomString method:

```
// 6-characters give you a little over 2 billion possible 
// combinations (36 ^ 6). 7 characters is about 78 billion.
Console.WriteLine(generator.GetRandomString(length: 6));
```

The basic principle behind it is:

- Get microseconds since epoch (64-bit number)
- Get random number (64-bit) between 0 and (36 ^ desired length) (13 max)
- Get a servername hash (simple Sha1)
- Convert each component to base-36 string
- Pad left with `0` to desired length

The Base36 encoder itself is from http://www.stum.de/2008/10/20/base36-encoderdecoder-in-c/.